# How can I make request between two routes in Slim PHP?

Tags: php, backend, slim, slim-3

I have one route with registration functionality:

```php
$app->post('/account/signup', function(\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args) use($app) {

//new record to database

})->add(new Driver());
```

And another one with verification code generation

```php
$app->post('/account/verification/byemail', function(\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args) use($app) {

//Generate email verification code end send it

})->add(new Driver());
```

I want to call '/account/verification/byemail' and transfer some data there ('POST' method, or by HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header) after user will be created in '/account/signup'...

I've tried $app->subRequest(), but it didn't worked =(

Comment: You don't say how you use `$app->subRequest()` or how it fails to work. Do you need help with that or you just want an entirely different solution?

Comment: Instead of making extra requests, it's probably better to move your code into a class, which is then injected into your container object. You can then call methods on this class from any route.